# Best practice for an infinite loop Python script that runs on Windows as a Service

Tags: python, windows, loops, service

I have a python script that reads data from an OPCDA server and then push it to InfluxDB.

So basically it connects to the OPCDA using the OpenOPC library and to InfluxDB using the InfluxDB Python client and then starts an infinite while loop that runs every 5 seconds to read and push data to the database.

I have installed the script as a Service using NSSM. What is the best practice to ensure that the script is running 24/7 ? How to avoid crashes ?
Should i daemonize the script ?

Thank you in advance,

Bnjroos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest at least to add logging at the script level. You could also use custom Exit Codes from python so NSSM knows to report failure. Your failure would probably be when connecting to your services so, i.e. netowrk down or something so you could write custom exceptions for NSSM to restart. If it's running every 5 seconds you would probably know very soon.

Ensuring availability and avoiding crashes is about your code more than infrastructure, hence the above recommendations.

I believe using NSSM (for scheduling and such) is better than daemonizing, since you're basically adding functionality of NSSM in your script and potentially adding more code that may fail.